# One Drive API - Error acquiring access token

Tags: php, oauth, onedrive

I'm trying to use [this one drive php library](https://github.com/lovattj/php-skydrive), per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011047/onedrive-upload-via-php), however running into an error message acquiring an access token

> The client does not have a secret configured. If you are the client
>   application developer, configure a secret through the application
>   management site at https://manage.dev.live.com/.

It seems I do have a secret configure though; any ideas where I'm going wrong?

[image: One Drive app configuration]

Comment: As a side note, I only setup the private key when I ran into the error message. It sounds like I shouldn't need it though, based on some feedback in the comments section on the relevant page of the MS site. - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/#comment-2778324178

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We have the same problem here.

Comment: I never figured it out, gave up on one drive.

Comment: My own answer below worked for me. Had the same issue (that's how I found this question) and that solved it.

Answer (score 9):

It's actually quite simple. I believe you have to check the "Live SDK support" checkbox near the bottom of your app settings.

Comment: This worked for me. Do you know the reason why we need to check the "Live SDK Support"?

Answer (score 0):

Click on '`Generate New Password`' button and copy the ClientSecret value for further reference.

Make sure to match the redirect uri.